# How to remove margin at top of table?

Tags: html, css, space

**Edit:** I had some code posted here but I couldn't get it to reproduce. So here is the link to the problem:

http://stackmobile.quickmediasolutions.com/questions.php?site=stackoverflow

No matter what I do, there is still a gap between the table and the DIV. This occurs on Google Chrome 5.0.375.70 beta on Linux. (And it seems to occur on other Webkit-based browsers too.)

How can I get rid of the space?

Comment: If it helps, the space between the table and div is about 4px.

Comment: I seem to have pinpointed a possible clue: removing the DOCTYPE removes the space. Not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it!

All I needed to add was

```
height: 40px;
```

to

```
#topbar_logo {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There might be a space character between the div and the table. If yes then try removing that.

Try giving

```
body
{
    font-size: 1px;
}
```

and check whether the 4px has been reduced or not.

Comment: Aha! The `font-size: 1px;` did indeed get rid of the space. Looks like I have a whitespace problem or something. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following CSS:-

```
div {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
table {
    margin: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try zeroing the div margin too:

```
div {
    margin:0;
}
```

This is the full page I used, it seemed to work for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/\
xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            div {
                width:2em;
                height:2em;
                background-color:black;
            }
            table {
                background-color:red;
                margin: 0px;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                padding: 0px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Test</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ya, my example was quite poor. I posted a link to the actual site in the question - and since figured out the problem.